# How to get timezone, Language and County Id in flutter by the location of device in flutter?

Tags: datetime, dart, timezone, flutter

I want to get Timezone, language, and county Id when I run my project on my device android or iOS. It should detect Timezone, language and country Id from the location of the device.

Can I get these via the internal library?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/#tracking-locale

> Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

provides `countryCode` and `languageCode`

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Locale-class.html

The timezone should be available with (not tried)

```
DateTime.now().timeZoneName
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: Thanks @Gunter, but I am getting country code "US" and language id "en", how can I get it accordingly my current location, as I am in India it should show "IND"

Comment: You need to add `flutter_localizations` https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/#setting-up Let me know if this helps, I haven't tried this myself yet.

Comment: @AmmyKang are you using an emulator?

Comment: ```someDateTime.toLocal()``` works nice if you are using ISO timestamps

Comment: Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context); does not work for me. myLocale.languageCode is always "en"

Comment: When I do this, I get the error "Failed assertion", "Scope != null, a Localizations ancestor was not found".

Comment: I got same error of "Scope != null, a Localizations ancestor was not found"

Comment: No that does not work. It always returns a hard coded american "en_US" locale, whatever the device locale/country is. This should should not be marked as answer...

Comment: Do you have this code inside or outside of `build()`? I haven't used it in a while but I have some vague memory that this has to be inside build (or code called from build) but not for example in `main() {...}`.

Comment: The reason that `Localizations.localeOf(context)` does not work for everyone: it gives the locale _of the current context_, which is derived from the system locale but has been resolved to one of the locales in `supportedLocales`. This is a parameter passed to the `MaterialApp` or `WidgetsApp` widget, and the default is only `[en_US]`. Using `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale` gives you the raw thing.

Comment: If you guys are on iOS, do not actually forget to add supported languages in your info.plist otherwise you won't have it available.

Comment: This method doesn't work before the WidgetsApp/MaterialApp widget is initialized.

Comment: Also, `Localizations.localeOf(context)` returns locale that YOU defined as supported by your app in the `supportedLocales` parameter of the `MaterialApp` widget. If you didn't pass any locale there, you will get `en_US` always.

Answer (score 260):

## Flutter locales explained

First of all, you should understand the difference between system settings and your application settings:

- System settings - what the system provides to your app as user preferences for your information.
- Application settings - what *you* decided (explicitly or implicitly) to be the application locale. You may allow your users to select any locale of your app or let Flutter to do it for you.

## Getting current system preferences

#### Get the current default system locale

```
import 'dart:io';

final String defaultLocale = Platform.localeName; // Returns locale string in the form 'en_US'
```

#### Get the list of system locales

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final List<Locale> systemLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales; // Returns the list of locales that user defined in the system settings.
```

or

```
import 'dart:ui';

final List<Locale> systemLocales = window.locales;
```

## Locale of your application

The MaterialApp widget supports localization. It accepts the list of locales that *you* decided your app supports. That means *you* should explicitly define them in the widget initialization in the `supportedLocales` property and provide so-called "localization delegates" that will do the actual translation to a selected locale (the `localizationsDelegates` property). Providing delegates is required if your app supports any other locales except `en_US`. **When you request an application locale you will get an exact value from the list of `supportedLocales`**.

#### Getting your application locale

```
final Locale appLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
```

This works **only** when the `MaterialApp` widget is already initialized. You can not use it before the `MaterialApp` initialization. Obviously, if your app widget is not initialized, you can not get its locale. To use it, you must call this expression in a child component's `build` method. For example:

```dart
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: MyApp(),
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show the name of the current application locale
    return Text(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString());
  }
}
```

This will print the `en_US` text on the screen (because this is the default locale and we did not provide anything else). It doesn't matter what the system locale settings are because we didn't define explicitly any locale for our app in this example and thus it returns the default one.

## Catch system locale changes

To be able to react on system locale changes, you should use a stateful widget that implements the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin and define the `didChangeLocales` method that will be called on system locale changes:

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeLocales(List<Locale> locale) {
    // This is run when system locales are changed
    super.didChangeLocales(locale);
    setState(() {
      // Do actual stuff on the changes
    });
  }
```

## Full example

To summarize all the above, here is the visual example of getting locales on startup and reacting on system settings changes:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Get the initial locale values
  final String defaultSystemLocale = Platform.localeName;
  final List<Locale> systemLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales;

  // Define locales that our app supports (no country codes, see comments below)
  final appSupportedLocales = <Locale>[
    Locale('ru'),
    Locale('en'),
  ];

  final MyApp myApp = MyApp(defaultSystemLocale, systemLocales);

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: myApp,
      supportedLocales: appSupportedLocales,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // These are default localization delegates that implement the very basic translations for standard controls and date/time formats.
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // Store initial locale settings here, they are unchanged
  final String initialDefaultSystemLocale;
  final List<Locale> initialSystemLocales;

  MyApp(this.initialDefaultSystemLocale, this.initialSystemLocales);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  // Store dynamic changeable locale settings here, they change with the system changes
  String currentDefaultSystemLocale;
  List<Locale> currentSystemLocales;

  // Here we read the current locale values
  void setCurrentValues() {
    currentSystemLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales;
    currentDefaultSystemLocale = Platform.localeName;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // This is run when the widget is first time initialized
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); // Subscribe to changes
    setCurrentValues();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeLocales(List<Locale> locale) {
    // This is run when system locales are changed
    super.didChangeLocales(locale);
    // Update state with the new values and redraw controls
    setState(() {
      setCurrentValues();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Initial system default locale: ${widget.initialDefaultSystemLocale}.'),
          Text('Initial language code: ${widget.initialDefaultSystemLocale.split('_')[0]}, country code: ${widget.initialDefaultSystemLocale.split('_')[1]}.'),
          Text('Initial system locales:'),
          for (var locale in widget.initialSystemLocales) Text(locale.toString()),
          Text(''),
          Text('Current system default locale: ${currentDefaultSystemLocale}.'),
          Text('Current system locales:'),
          for (var locale in currentSystemLocales) Text(locale.toString()),
          Text(''),
          Text('Selected application locale: ${Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()}.'),
          Text(''),
          Text('Current date: ${Localizations.of<MaterialLocalizations>(context, MaterialLocalizations).formatFullDate(DateTime.now())}.'),
          Text('Current time zone: ${DateTime.now().timeZoneName} (offset ${DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset}).'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The supported locales are defined without country codes to show you how the selection of the current app locale works. Internally, the `MaterialApp` widget is comparing the list of locales supported by the app with the list of user preferences passed by the system and selects the most appropriate one.

Let's assume that we have the following list of system locales (en_US, en_GB, ru_RU):

** Click on thumbnail to see the full screenshot.

[image: initial list of locales]

Our app will look like this on startup:

[image: initial app state]

We see that initial and current values obviously the same. The app selected the `en` locale as its current locale.

Now let's change the list of locales to the following, moving the en_GB locale to top making it the default system locale:

[image: UK locale on top]

The app will reflect this change:

[image: app with the UK locale]

The app obviously still selects the `en` locale as its current locale because it is the closest match to both `en_US` and `en_GB` locales.

Now let's change the settings to the Russian language as the default system value:

[image: RU locale on top]

Our app will reflect this change:

[image: app with the RU locale]

Now you can see that the `ru` locale was selected as the app locale.

Hope this helps to understand how localization works in Flutter, how to get current values, and how to reflect system changes. The details about locale delegates are not explained because it is off-topic here.

PS: This code is tested under Android only. I think with minor changes it can be adapted to all other platforms.

Comment: your code need to be updated super.didChangeLocales and WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this)

Comment: also  WidgetsBinding.instance.window is deprecated. ):

Comment: Getting the list of system locales should now be `WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.locales`, as `window` is deprecated

Comment: Thanks, What else WidgetBindings do? does it return brightnessof system as well?

Answer (score 37):

you can use

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

String languageCode = Platform.localeName.split('_')[0];
String countryCode = Platform.localeName.split('_')[1];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I change the iOS Simulator to US Spanish. I still get "en", "US".

Comment: I fixed it a while ago

Comment: This looks better than solution with indexes.

Comment: This will throw a RangeError when `Platform.localeName` only returns a language code without the country code, like "en".

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
......
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// get system language code
    _sysLng = ui.window.locale.languageCode;    
...
```

Comment: Returns null always at the start of the app.

Comment: Always returns 'en' no matter what.

Comment: using iOS 13 there seems to be a bug as it returns null ... so I don't find this method reliable. From now on I only use     Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

Comment: Is not system language, is the window language but the system can have other language enabled by default. By example, when start an application with custom locale enviroment.

Answer (score 23):

If you write Platform.localeName, it gives you language and country like "en_US", "tr_TR".

To take just "en" or "tr", you can use substring() and take first 2 letter.

```
String deviceLanguage= Platform.localeName.substring(0,2);
```

It gives to you only "en" or "tr" etc...

If you want the country codes, use this;

```
String deviceCountry= Platform.localeName.substring(3,5);
```

It gives to you only "US" or "TR" etc...

Answer (score 7):

The steps to make it work are:

1. Add the package as a dependency to your pubspec.yaml file

   ```
   dependencies:
      flutter:
      sdk: flutter
   flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter
   ```
2. Import the flutter_localizations library and specify localizationsDelegates and supportedLocales for MaterialApp

   ```
   import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

   MaterialApp(
   localizationsDelegates: [
       // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
       GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
       GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
       GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
   ],

   supportedLocales: [
       const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
       const Locale('es', ''), // Spanish, no country code
       // ... other locales the app supports
    ],
   // ...
   )
   ```
3. **For iOS only**: open the ios module and add the supported languages under **localization**

[image]

4. Get the current locale

   `Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);`

You can access the **countryCode** and **languageCode** strings properties fo Locale if needed
[image]

Answer (score 4):

To extend on [Alexander Pravdin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825776/3302026):

### System Locales

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// or import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
final List<Locale> systemLocales =
    WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.locales;
print(systemLocales);
```

For example, this would return list of **Preferred languages** from chrome://settings/languages

### Locale used by Application

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// or import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
final Locale appLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
print(appLocale);
```

##### Documentation Links:

1. [`PlatformDispatcher.locales`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/locales.html)
2. [`Localizations.localeOf()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Localizations/localeOf.html)

Answer (score 3):

For timezone, all other answers will give abbreviations like 'CET', 'MSK' etc. and GMT offset.

To get the device's timezone in format of `Europe/Paris`, use [flutter_native_timezone package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone):

```dart
final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) plugin on a project, the current code will greatly simplify obtaining the system language of the device. Since the plugin has an extension for localeName

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

Platform.localeName.toLocale().languageCode
Platform.localeName.toLocale().countryCode
```

To get a timezone, there is already a good answer from [@Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50924050/14940072) with a link to the documentation

Comment: Thank you for editing. Is it possible to get the timezone from this library? If so, can you include that, since it was asked for in the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing in this library. According to the time zone, many answers were higher. I just suggested one of the easiest ways to get the system language and country if this library is used on the project

Comment: That makes sense, and is useful information. Could you [edit] your answer to make a note of that? It may also be useful to link to one of the other answers as a “signpost” for answering the timezone part of the question

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
import 'dart:io';
        
String getDeviceLanguage(){
  return Platform.localeName.contains("_")
      ? Platform.localeName.split("_")[0]
      : Platform.localeName;
}
```

There are some solution in this page like following but these codes won't work for **(Filipino Pilipino - fil**) and (Finnish - fi) and gives same result.

```
String deviceLanguage= Platform.localeName.substring(0,2);
```

Because according to documentation of Flutter:

> The result usually consists of
>
> a language (e.g., "en"), or a language and country code (e.g. "en_US",
> "de_AT"), or a language, country code and character set (e.g.
> "en_US.UTF-8").

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform/localeName.html

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html