# How to get current country code in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have already tried to get current country code via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923906/how-to-get-timezone-language-and-county-id-in-flutter-by-the-location-of-device).
Give me best solution for same.

I want to show country flag on the Splash page, So I need to know about user country and This is required for me.

Please help me guys

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50924050/1556386

Answer (score 19):

It's enough

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale.countryCode
```

Comment: what if I want dial code instead of countrycode

Comment: @ArslanKaleem then have a map file with all the country details. See https://github.com/natintosh/intl_phone_number_input/blob/develop/lib/src/models/country_list.dart

Comment: It`s clean nice

Comment: It is deprecated. Use `PlatformDispatcher.instance.locale` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can use system locales.

```
final List<Locale> systemLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales;
String isoCountryCode = systemLocales.first.countryCode;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't require to add explicit support for each country code in the `WidgetApp`'s `supportedLocales`. It just retrieves the system's languages configuration without the need for 3rd party plugin, which is what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 8):

From flutter v3.7.0, don't use `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale.countryCode`

'window' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Look up the current FlutterView from the context via View.of(context) or consult the PlatformDispatcher directly instead. Deprecated to prepare for the upcoming multi-window support. This feature was deprecated after v3.7.0-32.0.pre.

So you can use after flutter v3.7.0

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.locale.countryCode
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following package [devicelocale](https://pub.dev/packages/devicelocale)

Add the dependency in your pupspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  devicelocale: ^0.2.1
```

Import it in the class you want

```
import 'package:devicelocale/devicelocale.dart';
```

Then you can get the current device local by using the following

```
String locale = await Devicelocale.currentLocale;
```

#### References

- [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/devicelocale)
- [Github](https://github.com/magnatronus/flutter-devicelocale)

Comment: Getting **en_US** every time and this is incorrect because my device set for india.

Comment: Please suggest better way to do it.

Comment: @AkshayJaiswal did you get any solution to this? Facing same issue.

Comment: @SameerDonga did you get any solution to this?

Comment: @ChiragKothiya If you are using an emulator device's location is always USA, Did you try with a real device?

Comment: It will depends on your device Language. Try to change device language and check.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the built-in `Locale` class for dart to get the country code and language.

```
Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
```

To get country code:

```
print(myLocale.countryCode);
```

To get language Code:

```
print(myLocale.languageCode);
```

Comment: This is always giving en as countryCode

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the country where you are actually located, then you cannot rely on Locale because it is user settings dependent. For example if you are located in Kazakhstan but your system language is English(Australia), then Locale will contain country code `AU`. Simple workaround  would be to use this API: `http://ip-api.com/json`. The response contains a `countryCode` of the country where you are currently located.

A more advanced method would be to use device location services. There is a [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [country_codes](https://pub.dev/packages/country_codes) package:

Install:

```yaml
dependencies:
  country_codes: ^2.0.1
```

Usage:

```dart
await CountryCodes.init(); // Optionally, you may provide a `Locale` to get countrie's localizadName

final Locale deviceLocale = CountryCodes.getDeviceLocale();
print(deviceLocale.languageCode); // Displays en
print(deviceLocale.countryCode); // Displays US

final CountryDetails details = CountryCodes.detailsForLocale();
print(details.alpha2Code); // Displays alpha2Code, for example US.
print(details.dialCode); // Displays the dial code, for example +1.
print(details.name); // Displays the extended name, for example United States.
print(details.localizedName); // Displays the extended name based on device's language (or other, if provided on init)
```

Supported Platform:

*Android*, *iOS*

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work on Web. MissingPluginException is thrown.

Comment: Doesnt work, giving me back US when im in the UK

Answer (score 1):

This solution is already posted. I just created a safe function for getting Country Iso Code. You can get language as well using `languageCode` on `systemLocales`

```
 String getCountryISOCode() {
    final WidgetsBinding? instance = WidgetsBinding.instance;
    if (instance != null) {
      final List<Locale> systemLocales = instance.window.locales;
      String? isoCountryCode = systemLocales.first.countryCode;
      if (isoCountryCode != null) {
        return isoCountryCode;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Unable to get Country ISO code");
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception("Unable to get Country ISO code");
    }
  }
```