# Replace 0 in a phone number with country code

Tags: flutter, dart, phone-number, country-codes

I use a library to get phone numbers from a mobile device but most of the numbers start with 0 for example:03004444444.But I noticed whatsapp converted it to country code(+92).I want to know how how to replace 0 with a country code in flutter.

Comment: What is the country code in the example you gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace '0' with country code '+92' you can easily do that with `replaceFirst` method. But unfortunately it's not as simple as that.
We need to check it whether the phone is a valid phone first, whether it's already '+92' in there, or whether it's started with leading '3'

```
void main() {
  //   final String phone = '03004444444';
  final String phone = '0312345678901';


  print('original: $phone');

  // this regex assume after digit '3' there should be 9-11 characters after it
  final phoneRegex = RegExp(r'(0|\+?92)3\d{9,11}$');

  if (phoneRegex.hasMatch(phone)) {
    // if start with '0' then replace it with '+92'
    final String replaced = phone.startsWith('0') ? 
                            phone.replaceFirst('0', '+92') : phone;

    print('replaced: $replaced');
  } else {
    print('invalid phone');
  }
}
```

You can check the code in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=792e9813a38f4f2a0f608bded97a7a36).

As for dial code:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale.countryCode
```

will only give you country code like 'US' not dial code.

For `dial code`, there are many ways of getting it,

I would recommend using this package called [country_codes](https://pub.dev/packages/country_codes)

But in order to be used in widget you need make it `StatefulWidget` and then put code initialization in `initState`

```
import 'package:country_codes/country_codes.dart';

...

String? dialCode;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
    // Optionally, you may provide a `Locale` to get countrie's localizadName
    await CountryCodes.init();
    final CountryDetails details = CountryCodes.detailsForLocale();
    setState(() {
      dialCode = details.dialCode;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know the country code how to know that?

Comment: @MugheesAli I already update my answer and already test it in ios Simulator by changing the region in settings

Comment: It gets the country on the basis of the lannguage and most of the people select english as their language so I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: I don't think it's on basis of the language, I tried change the language but the region remain (for example `US`) the dial code will still remain +1. I tried only on ios simulator though, I haven't try on android

Comment: I am trying on a physical android device and it changes with language anyway I figured it out so thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a default country code for example.

```dart
String defaultCountryCode = "+92";
String phoneNumber = "03444000055";
if(phoneNumber.startsWith("0")
{
 phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst("0", "$defaultCountryCode");  
 print(phoneNumber);

}

//Output +923444000055
```

Comment: What if I don't know the country code how to know that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408567/how-to-get-current-country-code-in-flutter