# How to get a localized date string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization

In Flutter, how do you get a properly formatted date string that matches the user's (or device's) language setting?

For example:

In English a date is commonly written as "**Friday April 10**", in German it's commonly written as "**Freitag 10. April**".
According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html), `initializeDateFormatting()`, must be called to enable localized results from `DateFormat`. In code this looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

class DateTimeDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  DateTimeDisplay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DateTimeDisplay createState() => _DateTimeDisplay();
}

class _DateTimeDisplay extends State<DateTimeDisplay> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initializeDateFormatting().then((_) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    String dayOfWeek = DateFormat.EEEE().format(now);
    String dayMonth = DateFormat.MMMMd().format(now);
    String year = DateFormat.y().format(now);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Text(dayOfWeek, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        Text(dayMonth, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        Text(year, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is, that `DateFormat.EEEE().format(now);` always returns the day in English. Same as `DateFormat.MMMMd().format(now);`, which only replies the English month and date/month order.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong here? Or how to convince flutter to return a properly localized date? Your advise is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use second approach by passing locale in DateFormater like below code:

```
String locale = Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode;
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
String dayOfWeek = DateFormat.EEEE(locale).format(now);
String dayMonth = DateFormat.MMMMd(locale).format(now);
String year = DateFormat.y(locale).format(now);
```

Each named constructor of `DateFormat` takes a `locale` as an optional position parameter.

In this case, you don't even need to make your widget stateful.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

After taking a look at the documentation, i believe you need to tell the package which locale you want to use. Try passing a parameter to `initializeDateFormatting()` with the locale string you want to use.

```dart
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

initializeDateFormatting('fr_FR', null).then((_) => runMyCode());
```

To get the locale from the device use:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

final String defaultLocale = Platform.localeName; // Returns locale string in the form 'en_US
```

font: [How to get timezone, Language and County Id in flutter by the location of device in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923906/how-to-get-timezone-language-and-county-id-in-flutter-by-the-location-of-device)

Comment: Eduardo, thanks for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't work: `DateFormat.EEEE().format()` keeps returning days in English. No surprise, considering that the docs of `initializeDateFormatting()` mention: "**Both the locale and ignored parameter are ignored, as the data for all locales is directly available.**" So I guess there's something else wrong here... Do you have any ideas?