# Requested the Locale of a context that does not include a Localizations ancestor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the `Locale` of the user's phone at app start.

I have this `Widget` tree in the `runApp()` method :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
            locale: Locale(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode), // This crashes
            localizationsDelegates: [
              const LocalizationDelegate(), // My custom delegate to get translations
              CountryLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: [
              Locale("en"),
              Locale("fr"),
            ],
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              body: HomePage(),
            )
        );
}
```

the line `locale: Locale(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode)` cause a crash with :

```
Requested the Locale of a context that does not include a Localizations ancestor.
```

I simply want to bind this locale to my `Delegate` without going further in app.
So far, i put `locale: Locale("en")` to read my `en.json` file from my `LocalizationDelegate`.

Comment: don't use Localizations.localeOf(context) at material app level, it wan't be available at app level, either you can skip that locale: parameter  or  directly use default locale const String code, like this    Locale("en"),

Comment: Yes but how to get the Phone's ```Locale``` ? I don't want to use english by default and later change it, i want my app to be displayed at app start in the phone's langage. 
Later of course the user will be able to change it himself (in my app settings, put the langage he wants no matter the phone's)

Comment: Hello @Tom3652 Have you got the answer?

Comment: I wish i had. I have not tried anything else so far, i have other ideas that i will share if they work but i am still waiting for an answer for now

Comment: I guess, this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923906/how-to-get-timezone-language-and-county-id-in-flutter-by-the-location-of-device

Comment: Have already checked this and indeed it helps but doesn't solve this problem unfortunately, i will probably ask in the Flutter git repo about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also answer because @Jaydipsinh is right but the error i was making is that i thought i needed this line :

```
locale: Locale(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode)
```

Whereas it's useless.
You simply have to put `supportedLocales` values and if they match the phone's locale, flutter automatically use the langage for the given `delegates`, for example :

```
GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
```

Also, you can retrieve the locale by using :
`String locale = Platform.localeName.split('_')[0];` with no crash at app start.

Comment: Platform.localName.split('_')[0] is the trick here without getting context, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a MaterialApp or CupertinoApp to use Locales.

For ex,

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      localizationsDelegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
        Locale('de'),
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('es')
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const YourHomeWidget(), // All Localized Widgets must be placed inside home widget.
    );
  }
}
```

NOTE: Flutter Localization automatically detect system language and apply this settings to your application.

Comment: Actually you are right Flutter choose the phone's locale matching the `supportedLocales` value. If phone's locale is not in the supported list, i simply use 'en' then, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick without crashes:

```
import 'dart:io';

String locale = Platform.localeName.split('_')[0];
```

Thanks.