Flutter Localizations.localeOf(context) countryCode is always null
Localizations.localeOf(context) gives the correct langaugeCode but the countryCode is always null. Somehow, could not get references for this.
    Locale currentLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    currentLocale.languageCode // correct
    currentLocale.countryCode //null


My recommendation would be that you check if you are providing values to the supportedLocales parameter from the MaterialApp.
Example:
MaterialApp(
   title: 'My app',
   supportedLocales: [
      const Locale('en', 'US'), 
      const Locale('es', 'ES'), 
   ],
   // Other parameters
)

More information regarding nulls in countryCode here.

Thank you, yes this is what's missing. However, a better way was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923906/how-to-get-timezone-language-and-county-id-in-flutter-by-the-location-of-device
